# Add more attribute to available API request with Strava (running app)

Tags: strava, strava-api-v3

I am using add-in API connector in Chrome to request a connection with my Strava account (a running app).
My point is to automatically update any new activity of my club members, then show up on a google_sheet link for recording and statistics.

Unfortunately available field of API request return does not have the starting time of the activity as attached image.
How can I have it as well? Many thanks.

[Edit field pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrZxj.png)

Comment: It seems that this add-in uses https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getActivityById to get data; have you already tried rearrange columns / show raw data / click on more information in order to see start_date or start_date_local field?

Comment: Thanks Tezzo. Unfortunately, I have already check all available columns but cannot find my need. I am using timestamp instead.